# Limit number of concurrent connections in Apache2

Tags: apache, concurrency, apache2

Is there a way I can limit the number of concurrent connections to the Web Application running on my Apache Server.

**My server version is Apache 2.2.11**

Comment: From the comment to the limitipconn answer it looks like you're looking to block concurrent connections *from one user* (or IP) instead of the global one? If so, you might want to edit your question. Also, if you block IP addresses, be aware of large networks hiding behind a single proxy.

Comment: I am not trying to block concurrent connections from a single IP. I only want a cap on the maximum no of total active connections with Apache.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [limitipconn](http://dominia.org/djao/limitipconn.html) module.

Comment: The above link is relevant for Apache 1.3. For Apache2, the link is http://dominia.org/djao/limitipconn2.html. Anyways I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will useful to you but definitely worth a chance.

Maybe you can use the directives
[MaxClients](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#maxclients) and 
[ListenBackLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#listenbacklog)

Although they apply to the concurrent access to the entire server, not only your application, and on a resource base.

Answer (score 0):

We completely built an application layer thing that stored, checked and restricted the limit on # of application users that could be logged on concurrently.

If it got exceeded, we sent them to a 'waiting room' - worked like a charm.

So it was all application managed - we had multiple apache servers in a cluster.

We were not using the Zend clustering stuff , IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing:

http://apache.ivn.cl/#bandwidth

and you can find a debian package too

libapache2-mod-bw

Comment: Can you explain more about the module that you've linked to?