# the maximum concurrent users that tomcat 5.5 can handle

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, client-server, jmeter

I am working on an academic client/server project. In the server part we use Tomcat as an application container. Now I want to know what the maximum number of concurrent users that can connect to the server, when I use MySQL in server also.

I should mention that clients only send a HTTP request to the server and give the returned value, so every user make connection for only a minute so. Is Apache JMeter a good choice for me?

Comment: This is almost unanswerable, it highly depends on the underlying hardware, the tasks the server has to perform to service the requests. You will need to measure it and even then using a tool like JMeter is only useful to get a ballpark figure, because users don't act like the script or the traffic expectations are totally wrong, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to put a concrete number on this.  In addition to the various server-side implementation questions, it depends on what the users are *doing*.

Simply "connecting" to a webserver is almost meaningless, because HTTP does not rely on having connections open for any longer than it takes to complete a request.

> i should mention that clients only send a httprequest to server and give the returned value so every user make connection for only a minute so is Apache "JMeter a good choice for me?

You seem to be trying to say what the users are doing, but unfortunately I found the description incomprehensible.

JMeter is a tool for testing how much traffic your server can sustain.  But it won't directly answer the question of "how many concurrent users" ... because there is no easy way to compare a synthetic load generated by JMeter with what *actual* users do.

---

(Aside: Why are you using Tomcat 5.5 rather than Tomcat 6 or 7?)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on many factors like

1. Your server configuration
2. Connection pool size of tomcat (web.xml)
3. application architecture, query efficiency etc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795005/standalone-tomcat-6-0-20-000-simultaneous-connections

Answer (score 0):

Please refer :

1. [How do you increase the max number of concurrent connections in Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389496/how-do-you-increase-the-max-number-of-concurrent-connections-in-apache)
2. [web server maximum number of users apache can handle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747548/web-server-maximum-number-of-users-apache-can-handle)
3. [Limit number of concurrent connections in Apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450606/limit-number-of-concurrent-connections-in-apache2)

There can be many more solutions on stack overflow only for your doubt regarding maximum concurrent users.

Yes, Apache JMeter is good choice for your testing.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this document: http://tomcat.apache.org/articles/performance.pdf, which talks about various scalabilty parameters and configuration.

**In the BEST CASE SCENARIO (ideal settings, good resources, best program etc), I would say that Tomcat may scale up to `10,000` concurrent requests.**

Comment: @StephenC: A simple typo changed the meaning altogether. Corrected now.